# nginx rewrite from apache 1 rule

Tags: nginx

Hi need help to reqrite this rule from apache to nginx, trying all day but nothing:

apache:
^pimage/small-([^/.]+)-([^/.]+).jpg$ /img_on_fly.php?iname=$1&iuid=$2&isize=small

tried with all online converters, tried everything I found online and nothing. I have no experience with nginx but other 15 rules rewrited one by one, but all were simple than this, so if someone can. Also, I am not sure what is "location" for this rule in nginx conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following in the server element of your conf file

```
location ~ ^\/pimage\/small\-(?<iname>[^\/\.]+)\-(?<iuid>[^\/\.]+)\.jpg$ {
    try_files $uri /img_on_fly.php?iname=$iname&iuid=$iuid&isize=small
}
```

your conf file should look like:

```
server {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

you can just change it to

```
server {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    location ~ ^\/pimage\/small\-(?<iname>[^\/\.]+)\-(?<iuid>[^\/\.]+)\.jpg$ {
        try_files $uri /img_on_fly.php?iname=$iname&iuid=$iuid&isize=small
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Omar, thanks for try but this also don't work... Nothing 'hits' this location, actualy that is core of problem, what is location {} for this rule to be 'fired' ?

Comment: your conf should look something like server { ... }. I'll make edits to show you

Comment: See my edits. I added a "~" after location (a typo on my part) and I also escaped some characters in the name your searching on. Also I used named matches

Comment: Omar tried this, but still nothing, even make few "variations" but nothing, nginx accept this config/rules after restart, no errors in logs but simply this don't 'touch' wished location...

Comment: I just edited it again. Changed [^\/.]+ to [^\/\.]+. Do you have a URL to test with?

Comment: Oh, also try to add the leading slash to the regex like I did in the edit

Comment: tried everything but nothing. Yes I have testing url, so just add new rule, update on server and test it in seconds...

Comment: Omar BINGO, big thanks! Last edit (I didn't sow since I worked on previous) with ...(?<iname>[^\/\.]+)\-(?<iuid>[^\/\.]+)\.jpg$... works!

Answer (score 0):

What about escaping the dots, like so:

```
rewrite ^pimage/small-([^/\.]+)-([^/\.]+).jpg$ /img_on_fly.php?iname=$1&iuid=$2&isize=small;
```

try it and comment back.

**UPDATE**:
Try escaping the dashes too, like so:

```
rewrite ^pimage/small\-([^/\.]+)\-([^/\.]+).jpg$ /img_on_fly.php?iname=$1&iuid=$2&isize=small;
```

After try that, try also the variation of "dots not escaped and dashes escaped".

Comment: hi Nelson, thanks for this but don't work :( any other ideas? :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with two new possibilities, try them I think they will work.

Comment: You were giving rewrite rules for apache not nginx. Yours would cause errors